# Download and copy function is not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, download, filesaver.js

Download and copy function is not working on mobile devices but works fine desktop. Both in android and IOS.

Using filesaver.js for download and navigator clipboard.writeText for copy function. Any solution for mobile device?

```
<a class="download downloadFile" href="javascript:void(0)" download="" onClick="downloadFile">`
```

```
function downloadFile() {
  var url = $("#siderModal .image").attr("src");
  var imgPath = document.location.origin;
  saveAs(imgPath + "/" + url);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.